# Filter email via headers information in M365 using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to locate emails in mailboxes that contain certain email header information.  Utilizing the Microsoft Graph Explorer I am able to extract all 'internetMessageHeaders' for emails:
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders('Inbox')/messages?$select=internetMessageHeaders`

Which results in:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users('xxxxxxx-ef44-425b-b7a5-xxxxxxxxxx')/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages(internetMessageHeaders)",
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"xxxxxxxxxxxZXLAAASEk7/\"",
            "id": "kSlaEZXLAAASFWUWAAA="
        },
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"EZXLAAAKjXG0\"",
            "id": "AKj3OcAAA=",
            "internetMessageHeaders": [
                {
                    "name": "Received",
                    "value": "from x.x.prod.outlook.com (x:x:x:x::x) by x.x.prod.outlook.com with HTTPS; Tue, 23 Nov 2021 22:13:31 +0000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Received",
                    "value": "from x.x.prod.outlook.com (x:x:x:x::x) by x.x.prod.outlook.com (x:x:x:x::x) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id x; Tue, 23 Nov 2021 22:13:28 +0000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Received",
                    "value": "from x.x.prod.protection.outlook.com (x:x:x:x::x) by x.outlook.office365.com (x:x:x:x::x) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id x via Frontend Transport; Tue, 23 Nov 2021 22:13:27 +0000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Received",
                    "value": "from x (x.x.x.x) by x.mail.protection.outlook.com (x.x.x.x) with Microsoft SMTP Server (version=TLS1_2, cipher=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384) id x via Frontend Transport; Tue, 23 Nov 2021 22:13:26 +0000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Authentication-Results",
                    "value": "spf=pass (sender IP is x.x.x.x) smtp.mailfrom=senderdomain.com; dkim=pass (signature was verified) header.d=senderdomain.com;dmarc=pass action=none header.from=senderdomain.com;compauth=pass reason=100"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Received-SPF",
                    "value": "Pass (protection.outlook.com: domain of senderdomain.com designates x.x.x.x as permitted sender) receiver=protection.outlook.com; client-ip=x.x.x.x; helo=senderdomain.com;"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Date",
                    "value": "Tue, 23 Nov 2021 22:13:24 +0000"
                },
                {
                    "name": "DKIM-Signature",
                    "value": "v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=senderdomain.com;s=senderdomain; t=1637705605;bh=xxxxxxx;h=Date:To:From:Reply-To:Subject:From;b=[redacted]="
                },
                {
                    "name": "Subject",
                    "value": "Test #3"
                },....
```

With the JSON results available, is it possible to use the `$filter` operation to search any of the `value` fields for specific conditions?

For example:

1. how would I search/filter the `Received-SPF` field for a `Pass or Fail` condition?
2. how would I search/filter any of the `Received` fields for a specific string?
3. how would I combine #1 and #2 with an AND logic in a single filter?

I have looked at the [Advanced Query references](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/aad-advanced-queries), yet I am not able to find any reference on how to filter for values inside the `internetMessageHeaders` JSON structure.

Any thoughts or pointers on how to search the header information fields would be much appreciated.

The end-goal is to only return emails where the `$filter` criteria on the email header fields is met.

Answer (score 2):

You could filter on filter singleValueExtendedProperties of type 0x007D which  returns all internetmessageheaders as one object:

```
"singleValueExtendedProperties": [
  {
    "id": "String 0x7d",
    "value": "{headerName}: {headerValue}; {headerName}: {headerValue}; ....."
  }
]
```

If you want to use this filter:

```
$filter=internetMessageHeaders/any(r:r/name eq 'Received-SPF')
```

use this instead

```
$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(r:r/id eq 'String 0x007D' and contains(r/value,'Received-SPF'))
```

If you want to avoid parsing that one long string of headers, you can add

```
$select=internetMessageHeaders
```

and you get them as one long array of key/value objects

Answer (score 0):

The property `InternetMessageHeaders` does not support filtering.

You can try this request

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders('Inbox')/messages?$select=internetMessageHeaders&$filter=internetMessageHeaders/any(r:r/name eq 'Received-SPF')
```

But it will return `ErrorInvalidProperty`

Comment: Yes, the response will like `{
"error":{
"code": "ErrorInvalidProperty",
"message": "The property 'internetMessageHeaders' does not support filtering."
}
}`

Comment: So there is no way to filter/search internetMessageHeaders during an API call?

Comment: What about the $expand option? [Get singleValueLegacyExtendedProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) Is it possible to use that to search the JSON returned?  I simply can't figure out how the $expand option is suppose to be applied.